# Is the higher voltage part of this PCB correctly designed?

Tags: pcb-design

I have designed a PCB that drives 3 relays from ESP32 3V3 signals (coming from another board). The "top" relay (SLA-12VDC-SL-C) is intended to drive a 230VAC/3A pump, and the other two are intended for peristaltic pumps (230VAC/100mA).

I am not used to designing tracks for this kind of voltage/current. Here are the schematic and the PCB. I intend to add soldering on all 230VAC tracks to improve conductivity (is this required here?)

[image: Schematic]

[image: PCB]

Could you provide me with some feedback as to the tracks' layout? Are they OK for such currents/voltages?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151310/discussion-on-question-by-silverspur-is-the-higher-voltage-part-of-this-pcb-corr); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.